# CKEditor is saving text with extra slashes in HTML tags

Tags: php, ckeditor

When I retrieve the data from the textarea in the form,

```
<?php $editor_data = $_POST['editor1']; ?>
```

this works fine locally.

The remote server, however, returns the text mixing up the style with escape slashes, like this:

```
<h3 style=\"color: blue;\"> Initial value.</h3>
```

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

You can use stripslashes function (http://www.php.net/stripslashes) if you cannot modify php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Since Magic quotes has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0, stripslashes($string) is the way to go.