# CKEditor is putting \ on my page each time I save something with apostrophe

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor on my website and I have a seperate box at the top which displays the chapter name.

```
<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="'.$chapter_title.'"/>
```

Each time I save the CKeditor page when I have an apostrophie it puts a \ in the chapter name.

```
eg.  John's   becomes   John\'s  
Then each time I save it adds more \ 
so second time John's becomes John\\'s then third time John\\\'s etc.
```

Does anyone know how to stop this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor is saving text with extra slashes in HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749720/ckeditor-is-saving-text-with-extra-slashes-in-html-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your magic_quotes_gpc is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

[Disable magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Answer (score 0):

Read about the functions [addslashes()](http://pa2.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and [stripslashes()](http://pa2.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: They are php functions. I don't know chkeditor. You may want to look at the server setting `magic_quotes_gpc` in phpinfo and see if it is turned off (on by default).

Comment: how would i add the stripslahes code to the chapter title - or how would i acces the php ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Use php function stripslashes() before echoing the content.